# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() no idea

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

last_signal:

```
Unnamed: 0  coresym    Lots         open_orders    direction
0   0       AUDUSD     110.39       0.0             9.0
1   1       EURUSD     88.19        0.0             9.0
2   2       GBPUSD     -87.65       0.0             9.0
```

signal:

```
    coresym Lots    open_orders direction
0   AUDUSD  250.00  0.0         1.0
1   EURUSD  112.50  0.0         0.0
2   GBPUSD  -97.11  0.0         0.0
```

I want to change the signal's value based on last_signal:

```
if ((last_signal[last_signal['coresym']=='AUDUSD']['direction'] == 9) & (signal[signal['coresym']=='AUDUSD']['Lots'] >100)):
    signal[signal['coresym']=='AUDUSD']['direction'] = 9
```

I got the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-0b88b27047e9> in <module>
----> 1 if ((last_signal[last_signal['coresym']=='AUDUSD']['direction'] == 9) & (signal[signal['coresym']=='AUDUSD']['Lots'] >100)):
      2     signal[signal['coresym']=='AUDUSD']['direction'] = 9

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1327 
   1328     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1329         raise ValueError(
   1330             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1331             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I tried to debug myself:

```
last_signal[last_signal['coresym']=='AUDUSD']['direction'] == 9
```

```
0    True
Name: direction, dtype: bool
```

```
signal[signal['coresym']=='AUDUSD']['Lots'] >100
```

```
0    True
Name: Lots, dtype: bool
```

```
((last_signal[last_signal['coresym']=='AUDUSD']['direction'] == 9) & (signal[signal['coresym']=='AUDUSD']['Lots'] >100))
```

```
0    True
dtype: bool
```

I really dont understand why, I assume others may have the same problem, so I post it here

Comment: The line which gives you the error has `and`, but you posted your code with `&`, are you sure your code is correct?

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this, I was debugging, so this is a typo when I was posting, but with &, its still not right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice from the final output, you get a series after applying all your operations, hence you can't get its truth value like this:

```
condition = ((last_signal[last_signal['coresym']=='AUDUSD']['direction'] == 9) & (signal[signal['coresym']=='AUDUSD']['Lots'] >100))
truth_value = bool(condition) # will give you the current error
```

hence giving you the issue with your `if` statement. To overcome it, do this

```
if condition.any():
    # your code
```

`.any()` for a series containing a single `True` (at-least one `True` is enough for `.any()` to evaluate as `True`) will evaluate to be `True`. So basically do this:

```
if ((last_signal[last_signal['coresym']=='AUDUSD']['direction'] == 9) & (signal[signal['coresym']=='AUDUSD']['Lots'] >100)).any():
    signal[signal['coresym']=='AUDUSD']['direction'] = 9
```

Since the series you get after using `&` contains only one boolean, you can use `.bool()` too:

```
((last_signal[last_signal['coresym']=='AUDUSD']['direction'] == 9) & (signal[signal['coresym']=='AUDUSD']['Lots'] >100)).bool()
```

Comment: I use & as I need to make sure the two conditions are both true that the value can be changed

Comment: The result you get after using `&` returns a series with a single value either `True` or `False`. Using `.any()` on these will give you respectively `True` and `False` again, so it's correct.